# JSON problems ajax

Tags: javascript, json, django, ajax

```
me.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (me.checked) {
        fetch("/demande/transporter/", {
            body: JSON.stringify({ cin_mle: cin_mle }),
            method: "POST"
        }).then(res => res.json()).then(data => {
            tn.value = data['email'];
            tn.disabled = true
        });
    }
});
```

code js

```
class ReturnCredentilasView(View):
    def post(self, request):
        data = json.loads(request.body)
        cin_mle=data["cin_mle"]
        print(cin_mle)
        user=get_object_or_404(User, cin_mle=cin_mle)
        if not user:
            return JsonResponse({"User_status": "inexistant"})
        return JsonResponse({"email":user.email})
```

the view

The error :

```
 moi.js:10 POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/demande/transporter/ 404 (Not Found)
    (anonymous) @ moi.js:10
    127.0.0.1/:1 Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

I need to retrieve some data from the serer using ajax, but the errors above appears.
the view is working good on postman
me is checkbox element

Comment: `/demande/transporter/` doesn't return JSON. The mentioned `<` is an indicator for markup.

Comment: can you explain Mr Andreas?

Answer (score 0):

The response in this case from the server is a JSON so just change you js fetch method as below:

```
me.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    if (me.checked) {
        fetch("/demande/transporter/", {
            body: JSON.stringify({ cin_mle: cin_mle }),
            method: "POST"
        }).then(res => {
            tn.value = res.data.email;
            tn.disabled = true
        }).catch(err){
            console.log(err)
        };
    }
});
```

Also check your url because "/demande/transporter/" is returning a 404 you can share your django url patterns which map to this endpoint foe further assistance

Comment: Hi Ochom, urlpatterns = [
    path('',NewDemView.as_view(), name='new-dem'  ),
    path('transporter/',csrf_exempt(ReturnCredentilasView.as_view()), name='transporter'  ),

]

Comment: the url "/demande/transporter/"  on postman returning good result